# How to custom tooltip such as contains some button in grid's cell tooltip in Kendo UI MVC?

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-tooltip

In the cell's tooltip,I want to add some button or menu,such as open button.When I hover the mouse above the cell,the tooltip shows the button.When I click the button,it will  open a window. Can Kendo grid can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how you would do it with JS; all you need to do is use the appropriate MVC wrappers (`Html.Kendo().Grid()`, `@(Html.Kendo().Tooltip()` and `Html.Kendo().Window()` (although you may need to use plain JS for the window if you want to use the jQuery click event)):

Grid:

```
var grid = $("#grid").kendoGrid({
    dataSource: dataSource,
    columns: [{
        field: "Id",
        title: "Id",
        filterable: false
    }, {
        field: "StatusText",
        title: "String value"
    }, {
        field: "ToolTip",
        title: "Tool tip column",
        template: "<span class='tooltip'>#= data.ToolTip #</span>"
    }]
}).data("kendoGrid");
```

Tooltip:

```
var currentDataItem;
var toolTip = $('#grid').kendoTooltip({
    filter: ".tooltip",
    content: function (e) {
        var row = $(e.target).closest("tr");
        currentDataItem = grid.dataItem(row);
        return "<div>Hi, this is a tool tip for id " + currentDataItem.Id + "! <br/> <button class='open'>Open window</button></div>";
    }
}).data("kendoTooltip");
```

Window:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open", function () {
    var currentContent = currentDataItem.get("StatusText");
    $("<div>Current status: " + currentContent + "</div>").kendoWindow({
        modal: true
    }).getKendoWindow().center().open();
});
```

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lhoeppner/PT9eV/6/))

Comment: When I click the open button,Can I show the row infomation in the window?And the window show the "string value" in  the same row of the grid(like "some Text") ?

Comment: sure; as you can see, we're already accessing the model for the current row in the tooltip's content method; all you need to do is store that model in a variable accessible to the function which sets up the window (in the demo, this would have to be global); I edited the answer to reflect that